# How to make on redux store for two windows in Electron

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, electron

I've made two different windows with react and provide same store. But if i change store data in one window, second window doesn't changed. And idk know how to synchronize.(All Reducers and Actions made as on default React project)

**First provide(index.js):**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import store from "../redux/store";


ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App/>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root"))
```

First App.js:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";
import {addNumberAction} from "../redux/addNumber";
export default function App() {
    const {number} = useSelector(state=>state.testPage)
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    let changeNumber = number

    return (
        <>
            <h1>First</h1>
            <button onClick={()=>dispatch(addNumberAction(++changeNumber))}>{number}</button>
        </>
    )
}
```

**Second provide(index.js):**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from "./App";
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import store from "../redux/store";

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App/>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root2")
)
```

Second App.js:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";
import {addNumber, addNumberAction} from "../redux/addNumber";

export default function App() {
    const {number} = useSelector(state=>state.testPage)
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    let changeNumber = number
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Second</h1>
            <button onClick={()=>dispatch(addNumberAction(++changeNumber))}>{number}</button>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same store. Each time you use `<Provider store={store}>` it basically create a store for any components inside it. Calling two `<Provider store={store}>` will create 2 independent store.

Comment: And how I can use one Provider for two window?

Comment: @verbtobe you can probably use library electron-redux

Comment: I know it but I never used Electron before. And I want to find the snippet where connected redux with 2 react windows

Answer (score 0):

I tried to configure redux state to share state between browser’s windows. At the end, I found info, how it can be with hook.
For example,

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    function HelloStorage() {
      const [name, setName] = useState("");
      useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("name", name);
      }, [name]);
      useEffect(() => {
        const onReceiveMessage = (e) => {
          const { key, newValue } = e;
          if (key === "name") {
            setName(newValue);
          }
        };
        window.addEventListener("storage", onReceiveMessage);
        return () => {
          window.removeEventListener("storage", onReceiveMessage);
        };
      }, []);
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setName(e.target.value);
      };
      return <input value={name} onChange={handleChange} />;
    }
```

For this [link](https://english.io/a-react-hook-to-share-state-between-browser-windows-a672470f66ff%5D%5B1%5D) you can find information, how create a custom React Hook to share state between browser tabs without Redux state.

Answer (score 0):

You can use redux-state-sync for that (https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-state-sync).

Lets say you create the store currently like this:

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer
});
```

All you need is adding the middleware to the store:

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { createStateSyncMiddleware, initMessageListener } from 'redux-state-sync'

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer,
  middleware: [createStateSyncMiddleware()],
});
initMessageListener(store);
```